# Django: Group and then Calculate the Sum of the column values through query

Tags: javascript, django, charts, grouping, aggregation

I have a model:

```
lifecycle_status_choice = (
    ('Lead', 'Lead'),
    ('Opportunity', 'Opportunity'),
    ('Customer', 'Customer'),
)
    
bill_status_choice = (
    ('Paid','Paid'),
    ('Pending','Pending'),
    ('Partially Paid','Partially Paid'),
)
class Bill(models.Model):
    company_name    = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grand_tot       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=bill_status_choice)
lifecycle_status    = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=lifecycle_status_choice) 
    ...
```

which has a fk to:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    associated_company  = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    ...
```

**Views.py**

```
...
from bills.models import Bill
from django.db.models import Sum

def home(request):
    data = Bill.objects.all().order_by('date')
    context = {
        'data ':data ,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html',context)
```

Front end chartsjs:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: [
                    {% for data in data %} '{{data.company_name}}', {% endfor %}
            ],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [{% for data in data %} {{ data.grand_tot }}, {% endfor %}],
```

The problem:
I am using charts.js in my front end template and I am trying to display a chart in which as a user creates new company names the chart should display the total amount grouped by company names how would I achieve that?

eg:
I create two invoices for "xyz" company with amounts: $100 & $200 || & create one invoice for "abc" company with amount $100
I want the chart to group the "xyz" invoice amounts and display $300 (ie:100+200) || & "abc" = $100

FYI I'm aware I'm using something completely wrong in the view function but its just something that I tried.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Contact.objects.annotate(bills_total=Sum('bill__grand_tot'))
```

The `Contact` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.bills_total`.

You can filter this with as satus paid with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

contacts = Contact.objects.annotate(bills_total=Sum('bill__grand_tot', filter=Q(bill__status='Paid')))
```

You can thus for example render this with:

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
    {{ contact.associated_company }}: {{ contact.bills_total }}
{% endfor %}
```

or convert it to a list of Python dictionaries for example and then return it as a JSON blob.

Comment: Hi Willem, The answer you posted throws an error as "Cannot resolve keyword 'bills_total' into field. choices are.." and anyway neither do I see that you have grouped the company names anywhere.... the output that your code would generate even if it did run I assume would be similar to mine which outputs each companies individual total without grouping them

Comment: @Ryan: sorry, it is `.annotate(..)` not `.filter(..)`.

Comment: @Ryan: as for the view you post, this calculates the total number of `Bill`s for *all* companies together, not *per* `Contact`.

Comment: thanks for the correction the code runs but nothing displays in the front end i have added my front end code to the original question

Comment: @Ryan: you passed the variable as `total`, not `data`, you thus enumerate over it with `{% for data in total %}`.

Comment: sorry and i also realized I posted the wrong view too :P just added the corrected version

Comment: @Ryan: but is `data` the `Contact.objects.annotate(bills_total=Sum('bill__grand_tot', filter=Q(bill__status='Paid')))` queryset? Then these are `Contact`s, not `Bill`s, so you render these with `{{ data.associated_company }}` and `{{ data.bills_total }}`, not with `{{ data.company_name }}` and `{{ data.grand_tot }}`.

Comment: @Ryan: I would also advise in your final code that you make use of either a `JsonResponse` (from some other view that provides the data), or by constructing a list of dictionaries and making use of the `|json_script` template filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

Comment: okay thanks will look into the JsonResponse method more and will update it here if I'm successful!